# Kubernetes (EKS) ingress error "403 forbidden"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, http-status-code-403

I have an AWS EKS cluster running and there I have a web application exposed outside via ingress.The web page opens perfectly but then when I try to login (enter the user credentials) to the website I receive the "403 forbidden" error. Couple days ago the application was working without issues and I was able to login flawlessly. I don't know what happened that causes this error. Here is my ingress configuration.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ns
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.website.io
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: example-service
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
```

I tried to run the same image on docker which works and I'm able to login so I have no problems with the image I'm using. I tried to delete nginx ingress controller and started again having new load balancer didn't solve the issue.

Comment: So with the application update you did NOT authenticate yourself anymore, going back to the version you had installed some time ago, when you had done the tests, does this authentication work? Do you always authenticate from the Virtual Host configured in the Ingress?

Comment: Because as written, it would appear that the application image has been updated and for some reason the login setup has changed. If so, please add these configurations to the core of the question.

Comment: The login stays the same, the setup did not change in the update I'm still able to login with using docker image, same image I use on the kubernetes.The authentication works as expected on the virtual host in the ingress.